# Convert List to Dictionary (a map of key and the filtered list as value)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda

```
class Animal
    {
        public FoodTypes Food { get;set;} 
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    enum FoodTypes
    {
        Herbivorous,
        Carnivorous
    }

    class Util
    {
        public static Dictionary<FoodTypes,List<Animal>> GetAnimalListBasedOnFoodType(List<Animal> animals)
        {
            Dictionary<FoodTypes, List<Animal>> map = new Dictionary<FoodTypes, List<Animal>>();
            var foodTypes = animals.Select(o => o.Food).Distinct();
            foreach(var foodType in foodTypes)
            {
                if (!map.ContainsKey(foodType))
                    map.Add(foodType, null);
                map[foodType] = animals.Where(o => o.Food == foodType).ToList();
            }
            return map;
        }
    }
```

The above code is to get the idea of what I am trying to achieve. Now, the question is 
**Is it possible to achieve the functionality of GetAnimalListBasedOnFoodType in a single lambda expression?**

Comment: you would normally use a Lookup, not a dictionary. In your case that would be `animals.ToLookup(a => a.FoodTypes)`

Comment: what @Martijn said, or `GroupBy` + `ToDictionary`

Comment: What about pigs? They are both. I.e. Omnivores.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
public static Dictionary<FoodTypes, List<Animal>> GetAnimalListBasedOnFoodType(List<Animal> animals)
{
    return animals
        .GroupBy(animal => animal.Food)
        .ToDictionary(
            group => group.Key,
            group => group.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the GroupBy method passing in the property that you want to group the animals by. Then, you can use the ToDictionary method to create your dictionary based on the grouping.

For example:

```
public static Dictionary<FoodTypes, List<Animal>> GetAnimalListBasedOnFoodType(List<Animal> animals)
{
    var animalFoodMap = animals.GroupBy(animal => animal.Food)
                               .ToDictionary(animalGroup => animalGroup.Key, x => animalGroup.ToList());

    return animalFoodMap;
}
```